# Where do files get saved in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which writes some JSON data in a text file:

```
FileOutputStream fOut;
fOut = openFileOutput("myfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
osw.write(myJSONData);
```

I am testing this application on the device and when I plug it in my computer, I am not able to see the file. Can you please tell me under which directory is it stored and do I need to set the operating mode of the file to `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` in order to see it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging it into your computer is mounting it to the SD card, usually. To save to that, get the SD card root directory File with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and then construct a new File with that File and your desired string filename as the arguments. That will save it to your SD card which should be the first folder you see when you mount it on your computer.

By the way, for writing text/JSON straight to a file, just use [FileWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Comment: I downloaded a FileManager app on my phone and I can see the files, but when I plug it in my computer, I am still not able to see the files. Do you know why please?

Comment: Did you try what I said or are you still using your original code? If you're saving to the SD card then you probably need to dismount it on the phone (there's a notification that says "USB Connected-Select to copy files to/from your computer", click it). Also make sure you have the right USB drivers for your device. Some won't work without them.

Comment: My phone doesn't accept SD cards. When I open the file explorer on my computer it doesn't seem to be there, but when I open the file manager app on my phone, I can see it there i.e. I am checking the same directory, first on my computer, then using an app on my phone and in the latter case, I can see the file. It seems strange. Never mind, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

It saves the file in `/data/app_package_name/files` folder. This location is inaccessible to user through file managers - only your app can access it through code.

Besides, if you are really eager to access the private files then you need to consider the option of **rooting** your device.

Answer (score 1):

You can not see the internal files visually until mobile is root. If you want to see it then store it in SD card.

Answer (score 0):

To save files to internal storage on Android (as of SDK 23) get your application's file storage location using `getFilesDir()` and save them there. The files should then be saved to `/data/user/0/your.app.name/files`. See: [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

```
File filename = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename.txt");
```

Once written, you can retrieve this file from your computer using adb:

```
adb pull "/data/user/0/your.app.name/files/filename.txt"
```