# Need to find the location of .txt file in the root SD card

Tags: android, gps

I am attempting to write longitude and latitude values to a text file each time the location changes. The result of which should be a text file, stored on an SD card, that contains a list of longitude and latitude values. The application successfully gets the longitude and latitude and the toast notification pops up saying the file has been saved successfully. However, I cannot find the text file in the root of the SD card.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView textlat;
TextView textlong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textlat);
    textlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textlong);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            10000, 0, ll);
}

private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();

            textlat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textlong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));

            try 
            {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(textlat.getText());

                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) 
    {

    }       
}
}
```

So basically, where is the file with the location values? I feel I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: I don't think /sdcard/ would be ok. Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() (not always the SD!)

Comment: check this out from an older question asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429783/where-do-files-get-saved-in-android

Comment: dont forget to take permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: In addition to properly discovering an appropriate path, on newer devices, don't forget you need to invoke the media scanner before files will be available by something like the MTP connection to a PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to write to the root folder of the sdcard. This will fail due to security issues. Try this instead:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();
File myFile = new File(dir, "mysdfile.txt");
```

You can then later find the file in the directory `dir`. If you want the file to be private to your app, use [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Also check out the guide topic on [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: Works fine after implementing your suggestion.